# Issues accessing an array based on an offset in CUDA

Tags: cuda

This question more than likely has a simple solution.

Each of the threads I spawn are to be initialized to a starting value. For example, if I have a character set, `char charSet[27] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`, I spawn 26 threads. So `threadIdx.0` corresponds to `charSet[0] = a`. Simple enough.

I thought I figured out a way to do this, until I examined what my threads were doing...

Here's an example program that I wrote:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

__global__ void example(int offset, int reqThreads){
//Declarations
   unsigned int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

   if(idx < reqThreads){
       unsigned int tid = (offset * threadIdx.x) + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x; //Used to initialize array <-----Problem is here
       printf("%d ", tid);
   }    
}

int main(void){
   //Declarations
   int minLength = 1;
   int maxLength = 2;
   int offset;
   int totalThreads;
   int reqThreads;
   int base = 26;
   int maxThreads = 512;
   int blocks;
   int i,j; 

   for(i = minLength; i<=maxLength; i++){
      offset = i;

      //Calculate parameters
      reqThreads = (int) pow((double) base, (double) offset); //Casting I would never do, but works here
      totalThreads = reqThreads;

      for(j = 1;(totalThreads % maxThreads) != 0; j++) totalThreads += 1;   //Create a multiple of 512

      blocks = totalThreads/maxThreads;

      //Call the kernel

      example<<<blocks, totalThreads>>>(offset, reqThreads);
      cudaThreadSynchronize();
      printf("\n\n");
  }

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

My reasoning was that this statement

```
 unsigned int tid = (offset * threadIdx.x) + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
```

would allow me to introduce an offset. If `offset` were 2, `threadIdx.0 * offset = 0`, `threadIdx.1 * offset = 2`, `threadIdx.2 * offset = 4`, and so forth. That definitely does not happen. The output of the above program works when offset == 1:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5...26.
```

But when offset == 2:

```
1344 1346 1348 1350...
```

In fact, those values are way outside the bounds of my array. So I'm not sure what is going wrong.

Any constructive input is appreciated.

Comment: I dont think you understood the cuda thread, block concepts correctly. Please go through this [link](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/).

Comment: @SagarMasuti Can you elaborate as to where my understanding appears to be off?

Comment: My appologies if I understood you wrongly. As per your explanation you want only 26 threads but you are launching the kernel with (blocks = 1,threads = 512 = 512 total threads) in first iteration and (blocks = 2, threads = 1024 = 2048 total threads) in the second iteration.

Comment: @SagarMasuti Ah, not quite. I am launching 512 threads during the first iteration, but the thread check only does work on 26. The second launch is 1024 threads, and work is only done on 676. The offset is to access an array within the kernel function.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your kernel call should look like this:

```
  example<<<blocks, maxThreads>>>(offset, reqThreads);
```

Your intent is to launch thread blocks of 512 threads, so that number (`maxThreads`) should be your second kernel config parameter, which is the number of threads per block.

Also, this is deprecated:

```
  cudaThreadSynchronize();
```

Use this instead:

```
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
```

And if you use `printf` from the kernel for a large amount of output, you can [lose some of the output if you exceed the buffer](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#limitations).

Finally, I'm not sure your reasoning is correct about the range of indices that will be printed.

When offset = 2 (the second pass through the loop), then 26^2 = 676, and you will then end up with 1024 threads, (in 2 thread blocks, if you make the above fixes).  The second threadblock will have

```
tid = (2*threadIdx.x) + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
         (0..164)       (512)         (1)
```

So the second threadblock should print out indices of 512 (minimum) up to (2*164) + 512 = 900

(164 = 675 - 511)

The first threadblock should print out indices of:

```
tid = (2*threadIdx.x) + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x
          (0..511)       (512)           (0)
```

i.e. 0 to 1022

Comment: Yes, something is wrong with my logic here. The intent is to only have 676 threads, but I rounded that to 1024 for the launch. To be specific, I'll have an array of 676 combinations of length 2 for a total of 1352 characters. Each thread is offset by 2 characters. The threads read 2 characters (they are offset by 2) via a loop, and in the end, there are 676 threads .

Comment: Actually I forgot you had a thread check.  So I modified my answer.  Your thread check (which is good to have) prevents any thread higher than 676 from executing.  This doesn't affect any of the threads in the first block, but limits some of the threads in the second block from executing.  I think it still creates odd indexing for you, however.

Comment: Something is definitely off. In my full program, the initialization of the thread only works for thread 0. It has to be something with `tid`. When I run this example, when offset is not 1, the numbers appear entirely random. (I don't use printf in my actual program). This is just to see what is going on.

Comment: If you are running this code on a cc 1.x device, you cannot launch threadblocks larger than 512.  So you have to make that fix I indicated in the kernel line.  Otherwise you'll get random, garbage values.

Comment: I believe part of my issue is in the `offset * threadIdx.x`. The first  block seems to have the correct spacing, but once it reaches the second block - or anymore - it restarts the thread count at 0.

Comment: Actually, I think the easiest solution would be to simply do `tid = idx*offset`. That should give me what I want